# how to get the differences of values that are in one slice?

Tags: go

Instead of a slice, i have to retrieve words from a file and i have to only output words whereby the letters are of running letters like feed, and bcd

So i came up with this func, whereby r []rune is the int representative of the alphabets and line is the words from the file. This function supposedly minus the value in position k and the value in position m, and if the output is either 0 or 1, it will return bool. But i can't get this  if l[k]-l[m]=0 | l[k]-l[m]=1{ to work

```
func differenceofint(r []rune, line string) bool{
        for i, j := range r{
        k := int(i) //position
        l := int(j) //the int representative
        m:=int (i+1)
        fmt.Println(k, l,m)
        if l[k]-l[m]=0 | l[k]-l[m]=1{
           return true
        }
    }
return false
}
```

Comment: In your code, you first assign an int value to `l`; then two lines later you try to read it as if it is an array/slice. Should the `if` really be `if line[k]-line[m] == 0 || line[k]-line[m] == 1 {` ?

Comment: i actually wanted the if function to read the int values, but i don't know how, i did the if line that you suggested but i got this as the output, 

panic: runtime error: index out of range

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if i understood exactly what want (bdc does not seem to be a running word) but here goes my interpretation:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "strings"
)

func running(word string) bool {

    evaluator := int(word[0])

    for _, v := range word {
        if int(v) != evaluator-1 && int(v) != evaluator+1 && int(v) != evaluator {
            return false
        }
        evaluator = int(v)
    }
    return true
}

func runningWords(line string) (result []string) {
    words := strings.Split(line, " ")
    for _, aword := range words {
        if running(aword) {
            result = append(result, aword)
        }
    }
    return
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(runningWords("algo atum feed bcd abcdef"))
}
```

and a playground link https://play.golang.org/p/A44Xed6Naa6

Notes about your code:

1. or is ||
2. i think you want to access the rune of line. l is an integer so l[k] or l[m] wont compile. i think you wanted r[k] or l[m]
3. if it is a long text you need to consider newlines, special characters, punctuation and several other issues.

Best of luck

Comment: running letters means for feed,it is from running letters of def, while trusts is from running letters of stu

Comment: while bdc is running letters of bcd, which means abcdef is also a running letter